# Error in original version of Odoo (fleet module)

Tags: odoo

when I install Odoo and fleet module then I can open user admin view. But when I upgrade fleet and I open admin interface a have this error (upgrade base module delete this error but when I upgrade next time fleet a have the same problem !!!)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 530, in _handle_exception

return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 567, in dispatch

result = self._call_function(**self.params)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 303, in _call_function

return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper

return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 300, in checked_call

return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 796, in **call**

return self.method(*args, **kw)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 396, in response_wrap

response = f(*args, **kw)

File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 949, in call_kw

return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 941, in _call_kw

return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper

return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1554, in fields_view_get

xarch, xfields = View.postprocess_and_fields(cr, uid, self._name, etree.fromstring(result['arch']), view_id, context=ctx)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper

return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 843, in postprocess_and_fields

self.raise_view_error(cr, user, message, view_id, context)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper

return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 367, in raise_view_error

raise AttributeError(message)

AttributeError: Field `in_group_12` does not exist

Error context:

View `res.users.form`

[view_id: 153, xml_id: base.view_users_form, model: res.users, parent_id: n/a]

Comment: and when i upgrade web module a have this error (normally it is the same error) :


Traceback (most recent call last):

Error details:

Field `sel_groups_12` does not exist

Error context:

View `res.users.form.mail`

[view_id: 230, xml_id: mail.view_users_form_mail, model: res.users, parent_id: 153]" while parsing /opt/odoo/addons/mail/res_users_view.xml:20, near

Comment: a officiel correctif since 8h but dont work with me :

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/98c1a82e681e9152bc68ee76b89e7cf029a7371c